# How can we say later that x can be equal to zero when we took x as a common factor and hence divided by it?

Tags: factoring, infinity

To solve an equation like this:

> $x^2+x=0$

We can take $x$ as a common factor

> $\frac{x^2}{x}+\frac{x}{x}=0$
>
> $x(x+1)=0$

However to do such a step we have to say that $x$ isn't equal to zero, because after all, if $x$ is equal to zero, then $\frac{x}{x} \neq1$, like we factorized. Instead our factorization should look like this:

> $x(∞)=0$

And even though we stated clearly that $x$ can't be equal to zero above, later on to get the solutions we state:

> $x=-1$ $or$ $x=0$

I know this is a very silly question and that's why I didn't want to ask my teacher about it. And I totally get that it doesn't matter in this equation anyway.

But shouldn't this be considered wrong, to state that $x$ shouldn't be a certain value to reach a certain step then when we are over that step and we reach another step we say that $x$ is that certain value we based our work on the fact that it shouldn't be it.

Comment: Your second equation gives the point:  we do *not* write $\frac{x^2}x + \frac x x = 0$, because, as you say, that *would* require that $x \ne 0$.  Instead we write $x(x + 1) = 0$, where no division has taken place.  Then one can cite "the Zero-Factor Property", or just reason by cases:  if $x = 0$, then, well, $x = 0$; and, if $x \ne 0$, *then* we can divide and conclude that $x + 1 = 0$.

Comment: But this is *not* a silly question, and you *should* ask your teacher.  Careless division of equations by things that might be $0$ is a source of a lot of computational error in many math classes, and understanding later (in Calculus) why it is OK to write something like $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^2 + x}x = \lim_{x \to 0} (x + 1) = (0) + 1 = 1$ is a very subtle and important point.

Comment: Notice that $\frac{x^2}{x}+\frac{x}{x}=0$
and
$x(x+1)=0$ are NOT equivalent equations

Comment: "This might be a silly question" It is certainly not a silly question, and it's great that you are asking yourself questions like these!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to solve your equation. First, we could deal with the cases separately. If $x \neq 0$, then we can safely divide by $x$, meaning that
$$
x^2+x=0
$$
implies
$$
x+1=0
$$
which in turn implies that $x=-1$. Then, we have to deal with the case that $x=0$. This is also a solution to your equation—we can verify this by plugging it in.

There is a second, more elegant way of solving the equation, that you yourself have alluded to. If $x^2+x=0$, then
$$
x(x+1)=0 \, ,
$$
which implies $x=0$ or $x=1$. Note that there is no division by $x$ here at all. Finally, you appear to suggest at one point in your question that $0/0 = \infty$. This is not true. In fact, $0/0$ is *undefined*. It is as meaningless to talk about $0/0$ as it is to talk about $\text{yellow}/\text{blue}$.

Comment: Wow, 0/0 is undefined... Now that I think a little bit about it it can't be infinity for sure!

Comment: @Manar In fact, $x/0$, where $x$ is any number, is undefined. This is because when we write $a/b=c$, what we mean is that $c \times b = a$. So let's imagine that $x/0$ would be equal to some number $y$. Then, $y \times 0$ would be equal to $x$. But $0$ times any number is zero, and so this doesn't make any sense. With $0/0$, there is the opposite problem: $y \times 0 = 0$ for all values of $y$, and so there isn't a *unique* solution. I'm sorry if you found any of this too technical.

Comment: No it wasn't. Mind you, at the beginning, I was going to argue you and say that it's infinity but then I realised it couldn't be and that I actually confused $a/∞=0$ with $a/0$. And it benefited me too because I discovered I never actually knew why $0/0$ is undefined.

Comment: I also remember now from where I got that $a/0=∞$. About two years ago, I asked my teacher why is $a/0=∞$ and he told me this: *if you have one pound but you have no people to divide it between them, imagine the earth was empty and there was no human left on it. Shouldn't you be able to divide that coin into infinity parts?*

Comment: @Manar If you go on to study calculus, you will learn that although $a/0 \neq \infty$, we can say that $$\lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{a}{x}=\infty \text{ for $a \neq 0$}\, .$$Although the details are a little technical, what this is saying is that as $x$ gets smaller and smaller, $a/x$ gets bigger and bigger. '$\lim$' is short for limit—limits tell us about what happens when you get close to a number, but you don't actually get there. Here, we are talking about what happens as you get close to zero, but not what happens *at zero*.

Answer (score 1):

The 4 biggest words in math are If, Then, Or, And.  For practice, write  whole math arguments  in complete grammatically correct sentences and do not omit the big 4. And do not omit any justifications.

Illogical: If $x^2+x=0$ then $x+1=(x^2+x)/x=0/x=0.$

Logical: If $x^2+x=0$ and if $x\ne 0$ then $x+1=(x^2+x)/x=0/x=0.$

"Illogical" includes an unwarranted hidden assumption that division by $x$ is possible. But "Logical" above still doesn't answer the whole  original Q, because it includes an extra "if" (i.e. if $x\ne 0$) that's not in the original Q.

Complete: $x^2+x=0\iff x(x+1)=0$ [by the Distributive Law] $\iff (x=0\lor x+1=0)$ [by a basic axiom of arithmetic] $\iff (x=0\lor x=-1)$ [Let's not get too tedious; you can skip the justification for this].

It is especially useful when you can manage to have all "$\iff$", as then the argument reads logically in reverse order.